# 3 models association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 3 models in my rails app Users, Shops, Products. Users can add shop and can add products to his/her shop.

**Users.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
         has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
         has_one :shop
end
```

**Shop.rb**

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :imageshop, ImageUploader
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :imagetwo, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :imagethree, ImageUploader
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Am new to rails and can't figure out how to add associate products with shops. If you guys can help it would really mean so much to me.

Comment: It looks like the `Product` should belong to `Shop` and the `Shop` should have many `:products`. Am I correct?

Comment: yes @MarekLipka you are correct :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `has_many` association to `Shop` model.

**Shop.rb**

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :imageshop, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products
end
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :imagetwo, ImageUploader
    mount_uploader :imagethree, ImageUploader
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :shop
end
```

Also, add `shop_id` column to your `Products` table.
You can easily generate proper migration for this using:

```
rails g migration add_shop_id_to_products shop:references
```

For more on Rails associations, [visit Active Record Associations, Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: hey @Saqib Shahzad thanks for your answer, although when creating the migration i get this: `class AddShopIdToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :products, :shop, foreign_key: true
  end
end`

Is not this looks odd to you as rails hasn't added shop id as a column. or is perfect?

Comment: This is perfectly fine, rails will create this migration, after this run `rails db:migrate` to migrate this migration.

Comment: thanks for your help i did that and it worked perfectly but while adding a new product am getting this error 
`1 error prohibited this product from being saved:

    Shop must exist

`

Comment: probably you are not submitting shop_id in your form while creating a new product, and if you are submitting it, you might not have added shop_id to your product_params in products_controller

Comment: thanks @Saqib Shahzad it worked...but when i push it on heroku it gives the following error ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'shop_id' for Product.): i have done the heroku run rake db:migrate....i have added this in my def new of my products_controller `@product = current_user.shop.products.build`

Comment: well sorry to disturb you, i solved it by running heroku restart